# Remove duplicate lines between sets of tags only

Tags: python, xml

I'm processing a text file (that will ultimately be converted to an XML file) that looks a bit like this:

```xml
<tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
</tag>
<tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
</tag>
etc.
```

I want to remove the duplicate lines between each set of tags, i.e. only have one "cat1" line between each set. I've got this bit of code to remove any duplicate lines in general:

```
input_file = "input.txt"
with open(input_file, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line not in new_lines:
            new_lines.append(line)

out = "output.txt"
with open(out, "w") as file2:
    file2.write("\n".join(new_lines))
```

Is there a way to iterate this over each of the separate instances of tags?

Comment: Is `<cat1>Data<cat1>` intentional or it should be `<cat1>Data</cat1>`?

Comment: Yes sorry, oversight on my part - those are correct in my original file! Will edit

Comment: new_lines in the first with block wouldn't be available in the second except you make it global.

Comment: If you can convert the file to xml first, then deleting duplicate elements should be relatively straight forward. That assumes the text file is otherwise well-formed xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
<tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
</tag>
<tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
</tag>
etc.
```

then create file `unique.py` with following content

```
import fileinput
seen = set()
for line in fileinput.input(encoding="utf-8"):
    if '</tag>' in line:
        seen.clear()
    if line not in seen:
        print(line, end='')
        seen.add(line)
```

and use it by doing `python unique.py file.txt` to get output

```
<tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
</tag>
<tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
</tag>
etc.
```

Explanation: I use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) to iterate over lines, observe that instead of providing filename to it, you might use standard input, so if your file was created by another command you might not create file but ram it directly. I create `set` where I store seen lines, if encounter line with `</tag>` I reset seen by using `clear` method, then if give line is not present in seen I `print` it and add to `seen`. Observe that I use `end=''` as each line has its own end of line. Observe that my solution does not require `file.txt` to be legal XML document.

Answer (score 1):

If your XML has a root tag you can do this with the built-in `xml.etree.ElementTree`. *I assume you mean the double  and not the duplicated DATA(?)*:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str ="""<root>
<tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
</tag>
<tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
</tag>
</root>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
# root = ET.parse("in.xml").getroot() # if you would parse it from a file.

collect = []
for parent in root.findall("tag"):
    for child in parent.iter():
        if child.tag in collect:
            parent.remove(child)
        else:
            collect.append(child.tag)
    collect = []
            
ET.indent(root, space="  ")
ET.dump(root)
# ET.ElementTree(root).write("out.xml", xml_declaration = True)
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
  </tag>
  <tag>
    <cat1>Data</cat1>
    <cat2>Data</cat2>
    <cat3>Data</cat3>
  </tag>
</root>
```

If you would also compare the Data content and remove the row only, if TAG and TEXT is the same, you can extend the code and use a tuple `(child.tag, child.text`):

```
for parent in root.findall("tag"):
    for child in parent.iter():
        if (child.tag, child.text) in collect:
            parent.remove(child)
        else:
            collect.append((child.tag, child.text))
    collect = []
```